# One gpu uses more memory than others during training

Tags: python, memory, gpu, pytorch, multi-gpu

I use multigpu to train a model with pytorch. One gpu uses more memory than others, causing "out-of-memory". Why would one gpu use more memory? Is it possible to make the usage more balanced? Is there other ways to reduce memory usage? (Deleting variables that will not be used anymore...?) The batch size is already 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`DataParallel` splits the batch and sends each split to a different GPU, each GPU has a copy of the model, then the forward pass is computed independently and then the outputs of each GPU are collected back to one GPU instead of computing loss independently in each GPU.

If you want to mitigate this issue you can include the loss computation in the `DataParallel` module.

If doing this is still an issue, then you might want model parallelism instead of data parallelism: move different parts of your model to different GPUs using `.cuda(gpu_id)`. This is useful when the weights of your model are pretty large.